# How to use Google Cloud Repositories with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-repository

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Repositories from Eclipse, but when I try Push or Pull Eclipse show me an error message:

[image: Eclipse error]

I'm putting my gmail credential(Google Cloud Platform account) but it doesn't work.

[image: Eclipse]

Maybe we need another credentials ?

Or what is the solution?

Comment: Google cloud repositories have formally only support for Android Studio, IntellyJ and Visual Studio IDEs (See https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/features)

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Repositories now supports SSH authentication, but Eclipse's SSH is aging and doesn't support modern key-lengths.  That needs to be fixed (perhaps with 2019-06).

In the meantime I discovered an unofficial workaround using Cloud Repositories' *gitcookies* support.  The process looks like:

1. Navigate to your repository on [`source.cloud.google.com`](https://source.cloud.google.com)
2. Click on *"Clone"*
3. Select *"Manually generated credentials"*
4. Click on *"Generate and store your Git credentials"*. This will pop open a *"Configure Git"* window with a shell script like below.  Find the line beginning with "`source.developers.google.com,FALSE,/,TRUE,2147483647,o,git-XXX.XXX.XXX=1/YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY`".  The "XXX.XXX.XXX" is your Git User ID, and the "1/YYYYYYYYYYYY" is your Git Password.

   - From experimentation, the Git User ID can actually be anything.
   - The password includes the leading `1/` and is about 60 characters long. Note that the password shown on-screen is clipped: copy the entire text and paste it somewhere and then copy out the result.
5. Paste the Git User ID and Git Password into Eclipse.

[image: "Configure Git" window showing User ID and Password locations]

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your reply, it doesn't work for me, Eclipse shows me the same error message. Do you have another idea?

Comment: I've clarified the User ID and Password.  Please give it another try!

Comment: Thanks Brian, but I changed to github and it is connected to Google Cloud repositories. This is another solution (For now).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse git just works out of the box now, there is no need to do any changes.

The only thing you got to be careful is that when cloning a repository, you should use the **SSH authentication** method to clone.

[image]